# how to run a function inside function asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, instamojo

I am making a payment gateway for my web site and I have problem with my debugger. Even I have used `async` await even then some particular lines are executed asynchronously but when another function comes it runs sync. For better understanding have a look on the actual code mentioned below

This is my app.js file

app.post('/pay', async function(req,res){

```
let response = await orderApi.pay(req.body)  // First debugger goes here (1)
res.json(response)  // (need this line to be executed when pay function is completed) (4)
console.log(response)
```

And this is my order API file

```
exports.pay = async function (body) {
  var headers = { //then here debugger comes (2)
    'X-Api-Key': 'test_d5f178f6f910a5ec48a429d540d',
    'X-Auth-Token': 'test_f3f32cda3a7aafc2a188579530f'
  }
 

  var payload = {
    purpose: body.purpose,
    amount: body.amount,
    phone: body.phone,
    buyer_name: body.buyer_name, 
   
  }
  request.post('https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/', { form: payload, headers: headers }, function (error, response) { // (3) !!!
       var parsed = JSON.parse(response.body); // then it does not goes here then it goes back in app.js file (5)
      var redirectu = parsed.payment_request.longurl (6)
      return redirectu
   
  })
}
```

I am not able to understand what problem it please help me to figure it out
// remember the points like (1),(2).. they are the numbers where my debugger goes

Comment: do I need to use a callback

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to return what's coming back from `request.post` which means that we should modify the code to something like the following:

```
const response = await request.post('https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/', { form: payload, headers: headers });
const parsed = JSON.parse(response.body);
const redirectu = parsed.payment_request.longurl(6);
return redirect;
```

**Explanation**

The `return` inside the callback of `request.post` is returning after the function already finished executing and since there's no explicit return in the outer function, it just calls `request.post` and (implicitly) returns `undefined` without waiting for the `request.post` to finish executing.